# Is it possible to populate a DataGridView with alternating vertical columns?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview, tablelayoutpanel

I need to display data that will be hybrid "hard-coded" strings and data from a database. Specifically, every even-numbered column contains string values that are NOT from the database, and every odd-numbered column contains data. So column 1, for example, will contain values 1 through 12 from the database, so that the first two columns look something like this (and the same pattern repeats several times):

```
00:00    BoundVal1
00:15    BoundVal2
. . .
02:45    BoundVal12
```

Is this possible?

Right now I'm using a TableLayoutPanel for this, but the coding for that is a little pretzly (not a Steely Dan reference).

Comment: Yes, it's possible - anything is possible. What have you tried so far? If I were doing this from scratch I'd put the 'hardcoded' values in the database... don't they relate to the bound values in some way?

Comment: I don't have the authority to alter the database contents; however, I can, I suppose, transform the related value (e.g., "1" gets displayed as "00:00", "2" gets displayed as "00:15", ... "96" gets displayed as "23:45", but my main challenge is how to get these values to display vertically (in columns) rather than the traditional horizontally (in rows). It's working fairly well with dynamically created controls added to a TableLayoutPanel, but it has been decided to, if possible, use a DataGridView instead. Is it possible to present data vertically is the main question.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer to your own question, not an update of the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this working, based on code from Mohamed Mansour at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/ca89a857-6e17-44a7-8cdb-90d64a0a7bbe

```
int RowCount = 12; 
Dictionary<int, string> PlatypusPairs;

. . .

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // Retrieve data as dictionary 
    PlatypusPairs = InterpSchedData.GetAvailableForPlatypusAndDate(oracleConnectionTestForm, 42, DateTime.Today.Date);
    int ColumnCount = 16;
    // Add the needed columns
    for (int i = 0; i < ColumnCount; i++) {
        string colName = string.Format("Column{0}", i + 1);
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(colName, colName); 
    }

    for (int row = 0; row < RowCount; row++) {
        // Save each row as an array
        string[] currentRowContents = new string[ColumnCount];
        // Add each column to the currentColumn
        for (int col = 0; col < ColumnCount; col++) {
            currentRowContents[col] = GetValForCell(row, col);
        }
        // Add the row to the DGV
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(currentRowContents);
    }
}

private string GetValForCell(int Row, int Col) {
    string retVal;

    if (Col % 2 == 0) {
        retVal = GetTimeStringForCell(Row, Col);
    } else {
        retVal = GetPlatypusStringForCell(Row, Col);
    }
    return retVal;
}

private string GetTimeStringForCell(int Row, int Col) {
    const int TIME_INCREMENT_STEP = 15;
    var dt = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 0, 0, 0);
    dt = dt.AddMinutes(((Col * (RowCount / 2)) + Row) * TIME_INCREMENT_STEP);
    return dt.ToString("HH:mm");
}

private string GetPlatypusStringForCell(int Row, int Col) {
    int multiplicand = Col / 2;
    string val = string.Empty;
    int ValToSearchFor = (multiplicand * RowCount) + (Row + 1);
    if (PlatypusPairs.ContainsKey(ValToSearchFor)) {
        PlatypusPairs.TryGetValue(ValToSearchFor, out val);
        if (val.Equals(0)) {
            val = string.Empty;
        }
    }
    return val;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just build a DataTable object and set it as DataGridView's DataSource.